# Height of <div> not calculated in table-cell in IE browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 10rem;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.cell-top-div {
  height: 1.5rem;
  border-left: 1rem solid red;
}

.cell-bottom-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5rem;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 1rem solid black;
}

.cell-right-div {
  background-color: green;
  height: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="cell-top-div">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="cell-bottom-div">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="cell-right-div">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Chrome & Firefox:
[image: Chrome & Firefox]

Internet Explorer:
[image: Internet Explorer]

Height of cell-top-div is fixed whereas height of cell-bottom-div is variable and depends on right cell. I want to add a left border to cell-bottom-div but in IE browser height is calculated as 0.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution I've found is to remove position:relative from .table-cell and add it to .table. I think by doing this the table is determining the height vs. the table-cell which is only being given height by its contents.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 10rem;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;  
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.cell-top-div {
  height: 1.5rem;
  border-left: 1rem solid red;
}

.cell-bottom-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5rem;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 1rem solid black;
}

.cell-right-div {
  background-color: green;
  height: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="cell-top-div">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="cell-bottom-div">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="cell-right-div">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```